# JQuery dialog is not closing, reference error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have came across a problem. The dialog in my code doesn't seem to be closing. I have done it previously and worked fine, but this time I can't get my head around what the problem might be.
Here is opening the dialog:

```
$('#container').dialog({
    'autoOpen': false, 
    'modal': true, 
    'buttons': [{ 
        text: "Ok", 
        click: function() {
```

And an attempt to close:

```
success: function(json) { 
    if (json.status == 'S') {
        alert('Recipe added!');
        document.getElementsByName('itemCode[]').value = '';
        $(dialog).dialog("close");
    }
```

Firebug returns

> ReferenceError: dialog is not defined

I have done it the exact same way in other files and works fine. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change `$( dialog )` to `$('.dialog')`

Comment: Looks like you want to do: `$('#container').dialog("close")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call your dialog container to close : 
`$( "#containter" ).dialog( "close" );`

Comment: Such a simple solution, worked like a charm! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the open dialog box div by using id of that dialog box :

```
$( "#containter" ).dialog( "close" );
```